# Split text stream by hash value of first field in line

Tags: unix

I am looking for a fast filter that will take a text file on standard input, hash each line up to the first tab character, and put the line into a different file depending on the hash value (modulo some number of files). For example, something like:

```
$ cat > foo
a   1
b   2
c   3
d   4
^D
$ hashit -o bar -n2 < foo
$ cat bar.0
b   2
$ cat bar.1
a   1
c   3
d   4
```

The hash function must be consistent between invocations.

This is somewhat like the standard `split` utility, but I want to split on the hashed content of lines, not simply the number of lines per component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there are no standard utilities to do this, and a naive implementation in Python is too slow.

So, I implemented it in C in the open source project where I needed it, [QUAC](https://github.com/reidpr/quac). Hopefully this will be useful for others. (I haven't yet pushed, but that should happen within a few days.)

Answer (score 1):

So you need speed. That kind of speed likely requires C (though Perl might be sufficiently optimized). Unfortunately, buffering is complex to do manually in C, and slow automatically in Perl/Python/Java.

So one possible path to a least-pain C solution, assuming you can run on a 64-bit system and you aren't processing more than a few bajillion TB of data:

1. open the output files
2. `mmap` the entire input file
3. remember current position
4. scan until a tab, summing the ASCII values modulo your file count (possibly subtracting 31 from each character first), to get the code
5. scan until a newline or EOF
6. the contents are `mmap`'d. this is an array. write from start position to the new line to an ouput file. Use `write(2)`, not `fputs` or something like that, to keep the C library's buffering out of the way.
7. return to 3 until file is finished

The friendly kernel will take care of paging things into memory as you reach the end, so you don't have to buffer yourself.

Note that memory-mapped IO is not necessarily faster than `read`/`write` calls for bulk I/O, which this effectively is, but it will make the code substantially simpler than trying to write buffering logic yourself. A Python solution based on this general design may be fast enough as well.

Comment: Interesting.... does `mmap()` work on standard input?

Comment: @Reid No, it requires the underlying descriptor to be a real file. It operates on a file descriptor, so if stdin is a file, it will work, but won't work on e.g. a pipe. For a pipe you'll have to mess with buffering.

Comment: Turns out that on Linux at least, the default buffering for `getline()` is plenty fast.

Answer (score 0):

That (suspiciously like homework looking ;) problem sounds like a job for `awk`

```
awk '{ print > "FilePrefix."$1%YourModValueHere }'
```

eg

```
awk '{ print > "bar."$1%3 }'
```

**Update to fix missunderstanding:**

```
1) define outputfilePrefix and modoloValue
2) load inputfile linewise as positional parameters
3) iterate over all entries in the first column
   a) calculate CRC (cksum), and modolo CRC
   b) output first positional parameter ($1) to file (prefix.modoloOfCRC )
   c) shift positional parameters one to the left (discarding the current line in position 1)
```

code: just enter as single line in bash

```
preFix="bar"; modolo=3;IFS=$'\n';set $(cat foo); for i in $(cut -f1 foo);do target=$(( $(echo $i | cksum | cut -d ' ' -f1;) % $modolo ));echo $1 >> $preFix.$target; shift; echo $target; done
```

better readable for understanding

```
1) preFix="bar"; modolo=3;
2) IFS=$'\n';set $(cat foo); 
3) for i in $(cut -f1 foo);do 
       target=$(( $(echo $i | cksum | cut -d ' ' -f1;) % $modolo ));
       echo $1 >> $preFix.$target; shift; echo $target; 
   done
```

if you put it in a shellscript, you can even pipe in the file (with little modification..) via stdin

Comment: This solution seems to be missing the hashing step.  In the awk arguments above, $1 is the (unhashed) text in each line up to the first tab.

Comment: aah, i understood that OP means to use modolo as hash-function...

Comment: Not homework. The modulus operation simply reduces the number of hash values to match the number of output files.

Comment: @Reid update now includes hashing, didn't do benchmarking, but should perform reasonably well..

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't that execute a subshell for each line? Also I can only read the input stream once (remember, it's stdin).

Comment: Maybe soon i gonna have a bit time to actually do it nice and correct..  
God I'd wish I had 32h a day :)

Comment: But if the focus is on speed, you probably wont get around a real programming language anyway, and  it shouldn't be all too hard to hack it together in `C`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a python script to do this... since you said it needs to be fast, perhaps a CRC is a reasonable choice of hash function.

Try something like this:

```
import fileinput
import binascii

for line in fileinput.input():
    modulo = binascii.crc32(line.split()[0]) % splits
```

The variable `splits` should be set to the number of files into which you wish to split the input.  You can use the variable `modulo` to construct the filename where each line should be placed.

Comment: I did try profiling a relatively naive Python script. The hashing is consuming a pretty small fraction of the time (~5%). It's ~25% `io.write()`, ~25% `split()`, and ~50% unknown (because it didn't show up in the profile).

Comment: Cool, good analysis.  Was the Python approach too slow for your problem set?

Comment: Yes, it's about 20MB/s. My hope is for it to be fast enough that the disk is the bottleneck: 150-200MB/s.